# Texto acompanhar a div

Tags: css

Tenho um gráfico que me retorna da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de que o nome do produto acompanhasse o gráfico independente do tamanho dele, porém ele fica no topo. Vejam abaixo o código:

```
<td style='text-align: center;><div id="barras">
    <span>Cobre</span><div class='barra1'  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #CD5C5C; height:50%; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial">Valor: 5,0 <br> 29%</div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
<style media="screen">
    #barras{
      position: relative;
      width:80px;
      height:130px;
    /*  float:left;*/
      margin: 0px 10px;
    }
    .barra1, .barra2, .barra3, .barra4{
      position: absolute;
      color:#FFF;
      padding:10px;
      height:130px;
      line-height:10px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Jovem vou ver se faço uma resposta pra ti, mas tenha em mente que div dentro de table não é legal... Vc é obrigado a usar tabela?

Comment: Fox, não  olhei direito a resposta do @hugocsl, mas acredito que uma solução é colocar o nome com position absolute dentro do elemento do gráfico e posicionar pra cima, desta forma irá sempre acompanhar a altura do mesmo.

Comment: @sam foi por ai mesmo que eu fiz :), só que usei um after com o nome do gráfico, alinhado no topo com top:0 e jogado pra fora da coluna com o translatey(-100%) que é a altura do próprio elemento.

Comment: @hugocsl eu vi depois. Ficou muito bom e dei +1 com méritos.

Comment: Valeu @sam tmj!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jovem fiz essa resposta baseado no seu HTML, porém não é correto usar um elemento do tipo bloco (a `div` no caso), dentro de uma `table`, pois elas têm escopos diferentes, uma tem `display:table` com filhos `table-cell`, já a outra é `display:block`.

Visto isso fiz uma sugestão dentro do que eu entendi que é o seu problema... Eu usei `display:flex` nas `div` que agora fazem o papel das `TD` e um `container` que faz o papel da `table`. Com `flex` eu consigo alinhar os itens em forma de coluna (`column`) e usar as propriedades `justify-content: center;` e `align-items: center;` para centralizar na horizontal e vertical.

Com relação a *label* da coluna do gráfico vc pode criar um *pseudo-elemento* para cada coluna, e usar um `custom atributo` tipo `data-texto` para colocar o *label* no `content` tipo assim: `content: attr(data-texto);` e na div assim: `<div data-texto="texto" ...>` Depois vc coloca um `top: 0;` e `transform: translateY(-100%);` para colocar o texto sobre a barra independente do tamanho dela

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor como fica. *Tentei mexer o mínimo possível no seu HTML*

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 height: 130px;
 background-color: #ddd;
}
.container .barra {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 5px 0 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
.container .barra1 {
 width: 80px;
 background-color: #f00;
 margin: 0 10px;
 height: 50px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}
.container .barra1::after {
 content: attr(data-texto);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="barra">
  <div data-texto="texto 123 456" class='barra1' style="height:50px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">Valor: 5,0 <br> 29%</div>
 </div>
 <div class="barra">
  <div data-texto="texto" class='barra1' style="height:75px; background-color: #ff0;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">Valor: 5,0 <br> 60%</div>
 </div>
 <div class="barra">
  <div data-texto="paralelepípedo" class='barra1' style="height:100px; background-color: #0f0;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">Valor: 5,0 <br> 90%</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Hugo. Certo, vou seguir suas dicas. Me perdoe, acredito que não fui muito claro na minha dúvida. Gostaria que a palavra Cobre, ficasse encostada na parte superior dos gráficos, ou seja, que ela acompanhasse independente do tamanho.

Comment: @Fox.11 agora ficou mais claro :), editei a resposta para mostrar como faz. Acredito que mesmo vc mantendo a sua estrutura da div dentro da tabela essa solução do `::after` pode te ajudar a resolver

Comment: Perfeito Hugo. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: @Fox.11 tranquilo jovem, só tenha em mente esse detalhe da div na tabela, mas acredito que a técnica usada aqui vai resolver em qualquer caso. Boa sorte ai, tmj